# Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 - Find/Replace only able to find whole words

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, eclipse-luna

This is a strange problem I haven't been able to find an answer to.

In Eclipse (Luna v4.4.1), Windows 7 SP1, the Edit > Find/Replace dialog is only able to find whole words e.g. if I am searching for 'foo', ONLY whole words 'foo' will be found, but NOT 'foobar', 'barfoo', or 'barfoobaz'. It doesn't matter what type of file I am searching in e.g. .properties, .java, .txt.

Doing a search via Search > Search or Search > File works fine i.e. searching for 'foo' in a project will successfully find all files containing 'foobar', 'barfoo', or 'barfoobaz'. It's once I have a file open that the Find functionality in the Edit > Find/Replace dialog does not work.

The problem does not occur in any other application I'm running nor previous versions of Eclipse. I was previously using Eclipse Helios SR1 without this issue (and was on Ganymede before that), and am using a new workspace.

I couldn't find a option where this is specified functionality, so I am at a bit of a loss.

(Edit) Screenshot of the Find/Replace dialog:

[image]

Comment: In `options` group of find dialog deselect the `whole word` option.If no option then share the screenshot here http://imgur.com

Answer (score 2):

OK, I had another look at an older version of Eclipse and the Find / Replace dialog DID have the 'Whole Word' option - as well as 'Incremental' and 'Regular Expressions'.

I then **increased the height of the dialog box** in Eclipse Luna and Hey Presto the other Options appeared.

Seems silly but there was no visual indication that there were any more options hiding there that required the dialog to be resized.

[image]